# Error: validation: chart.metadata is required when using helm install Traefik

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am now install Traefik using helm(`version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.2", GitCommit:"19e47ee3283ae98139d98460de796c1be1e3975f", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.5"}`),follow this [doc](https://docs.traefik.io/getting-started/install-traefik/):

```
git clone https://github.com/containous/traefik-helm-chart
helm install ./traefik-helm-chart
```

give me this error:

```
Error: must either provide a name or specify --generate-name
```

and I am using command like this:

```
helm install ./traefik-helm-chart --generate-name
```

and give this tips:

```
Error: validation: chart.metadata is required
```

what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to give the exact path where the `Chart.yaml` file is located

## helm2

```
helm install --name <release-name> <chart-path>
(e.g., helm install --name prometheus ./prometheus/)
```

## helm3

```
helm3 install <release-name> <chart-path>
(e.g., helm3 install prometheus .)

helm3 install --generate-name <chart-path>
```

Answer (score 10):

For anyone else getting to this page by googling the error message (like I did).

I received this same error because my custom chart file was called "chart.yaml" instead of "Chart.yaml" (note the uppercase C)

Answer (score 3):

I received this error message because my only chart was in the directory "charts" rather than "templates"

This is what is expected:

```
.
├── [1.1K]  Chart.yaml
├── [  64]  charts
└── [2.9K]  templates
    └── [2.8K]  manifest.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the error because `Chart.yaml` was being matched by a rule in `.helmignore`.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error as I had removed version key from chart.yaml by mistake.